# Enable security for encrypting credentials used in a Java Spring Boot application that uses Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, apache-kafka, microservices

I am developing a Java Spring-Boot application that uses Kafka as a message broker. I need to ensure the security of the credentials used in configuration. What is the best way to achieve this in a Java Spring-Boot microservice?

Spring Security is one of the ways of doing it which provides authentication and access control framework. I want to know if this is the recommended way of doing it or is there any other better approach.

I would appreciate any advice or recommendations on this. Thank you in advance!